# Отключение проверки ssl сертификата .Net 4.5.2

Tags: c#, .net, mvc, .net-4.5

Как отключить проверку сертификата ssl в коде .Net C# как в Postman (Enable SSL certificate verification)
Есть запрос который через Postman с отключённой проверкой (Enable SSL certificate verification) работает. Как добиться такого же поведения как и в Postmen в .Net

Это не помогает `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };` 
Аналогичные проверки тоже не помогли (
Есть ли способ отключить проверку ssl certificate

Comment: а каким кодом вы отправляете запрос и какую ошибку выдает? у меня приведенный код отключает проверку

Comment: @ExplodingKitten Ошибка The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. отправляю через HttpWebRequest.

Comment: У вас .NET Framework 4.5? Я ничего не путаю? Если да, то вам нужно сменить целевой Framework на 4.6 или новее. В 4.5.2 по умолчанию не поддерживается TLS 1.2. То есть проверку сертификата вы таки отключили, но соединение не можете установить по другой причине.

Comment: Вот это добавьте для 4.5.2 `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`, для 4.6 и новее будет работать без этой строчки. (но я вам сочувствую, что вам приходится работать с таким древним фреймворком)

Comment: @aepot Да вы правы, скорее всего дело в другом! Только вот в чём! Это да 4.5.2 это старьё ( Но выхода нет, менять версионность это последний вариант! Хотя в данном случае я пробовал поднимать до 4.7.2 и 4.8 но результат тот же (

Comment: Операционная система какая? Семерка? SP1?

Comment: @aepot Win  server 2012 R2

Comment: TLS 1.2 по умолчанию отключен в Win Server 2012 R2 https://www.admin-enclave.com/en/articles/windows/305-enable-tls-1-2-on-windows-2012-r2.html, ну  и все что выше я написал, тоже валидно.

Comment: @aepot не мог бы подробнее написать как включить TLS 1.2?

Comment: По ссылке же написано, открывайте regedit.exe, и правьте реестр

Comment: @aepot разобрался спасибо! Поменял, но после перезагрузки сервер теперь не поднимается (!

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Вообще ваше програмное обеспечение безнадежно устарело и не является безопасным. Ваш сервер могут легко взломать, потому что он содержит очень много известных уязвимостей. Чтобы это исправить, нужно установить последнюю версию операционной системы со всем обновлениями. Смотрите логи ошибок. Так же TLS 1.1 официально объявлен небезопасным и вам так же следует его отключить. Многие сайты в сети уже отказались от его поддержки.

Comment: Кстати, отключая проверку сертификата, вы делаете так же дыру в безопасности размером с дом. Если вам не нужны сертификаты, используйте протокол без шифрования - HTTP вместо HTTPS. Если же разберетесь с TLS 1.2, то верните проверку подлинности сертификатов и обновите фреймворк минимум до версии 4.6, тогда должно все заработать само. Без отключений проверки сертификатов или явного указания версии протокола TLS.

Comment: @aepot к сожалению это не от меня зависит ( Проверку мне нужно было убрать что бы проверить вернёт ответ или нет, на постоянку убирать не вариант!  Обновить винду это думаю самое правильное решение будет. Но это тоже не от меня зависит к сожалению!  Фишка в том что есть аналогичные запросы и они работают и только один валиться. Магия какая то! В отключение проверки он даже не заходит. Хотя запрос формируется правильный.

Comment: Ну то, о чем вы сейчас говорите, только вам известно. Могу только посочувствовать. И нет, магии не бывает.

Comment: @aepot Магии нет! Всё есть БАГ! )))